# How to change Magento admin tab interface to vertical accordion

Tags: javascript, magento

Most pages on the Magento backend utilise a tabbed interface with the tabs displaying on the left and the content in the main container on the right.

I am looking for a way to change this (product edit for example) to show all the tabs on top of each other with a collapsible accordion.

I have noticed that the admin section does include the accordion effect I am looking for within the config section (ie config->general->countries options).

Does anyone have any tips or pointers on how to remove the left side tabs all together on other pages and have them displayed as a vertical accordion?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer to your question as much as it is a suggestion.**

Magento can do something similar without any programming needy. If you navigate to Catalog → Attributes → Manage Attribute Sets & choose the `default` option, you'll be able to manage which attributes are editable on a per tab basis.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of how to move attributes between tabs. However, I'm looking to change the interface as a whole so that the tabs are not located on the left but are part of a collapsible accordion design instead.